# How to resign when I can't access the designated portal to submit it HR says I have to?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, contracts

I'm out on holiday outside the country at the moment and don't have access to my company laptop. I contacted HR to resign and was told my resignation has to be put through a designated company portal.  I can't access this 'portal' as it resides inside the company Intranet. It is physically impossible for me to resign the 'right' way since I don't have my company laptop.

Can I resign by emailing my resignation to the general HR contact, and CC my direct line manager? Will I be in breach of contract because the firm may say I actually never resigned because I didn't follow the procedure?

Comment: @motosubatsu I don't think the issue is so much evil USA devs as it is that this seems very specific to the particular company and their resignation procedures.  We can say "yeah, sounds reasonable to email HR and your manager", but who knows?

Comment: It's not specific to the company imho; there are rules and laws about how you can resign that are explicitly _not_ company specific because governments don't want companies to be able to make it really hard for people to quit.

Comment: Agreed with @Mawg - how long is this holiday? Why can't you wait until you return, or why didn't you give notice before you left?

Comment: @DavidK  personal circumstances have changed so I have to resign

Answer (score 12):

I am not a lawyer. As others have said, talk to Citizens Advice or ACAS - but you cannot be prevented from resigning as that would be slavery.

With that it of the way, my advice: don't do it via email. Do it via an actual physical letter, signed using an actual pen with your actual signature stating that you "resign with immediate effect". Send this recorded delivery to the registered address of your employer as listed at Companies House - this is important as letters accepted at the company's registered address are legally deemed to have been read. Send a *copy* by email as well, but it's important to establish the paper trail - that means there can no dispute as to whether and when you resigned.

Then of course work your notice period in the most professional manner possible.

Comment: I'm not in the UK at the moment... if I do send a letter to companies house when does the date effective of my resignation start? The date which I send the letter or date which the letter was accepted ?

Comment: Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: @omega There are services which print and email physical letters for you. I believe there are both in the UK and USA (and some even publish an API!). Maybe this can help you

Comment: @rath thanks!!, will give those serviecs a go if I need to.

Comment: You don't send a letter to CompanysHouse. You go to the website https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/companies-house which has the registered address and lots of details about _every_ company that is registered in the UK. Not www.companyhouse.uk which looks like a scam site to me.

Comment: @omega Just send an email in the same spirit simultaneously with the formal mail to announce your resignation so they are informed immediately regardless of formalities.

Comment: @PhilipKendall There was a comment "so I send a letter to companies house" which obviously won't work.

Comment: You may be able to send international registered mail from where you are now.

Answer (score 3):

The [UK government's website](https://www.gov.uk/handing-in-your-notice/giving-notice) only talks about whether a company can require written notice instead of merely verbal notice. This seems to be written on the assumption that written notice is always sufficient.

> Giving notice
>
> You must give at least a week’s notice if you’ve been in your job for more than a month.
>
> Your contract will tell you whether you need to give notice in writing - otherwise you can do it verbally.
>
> Give written notice if you think you’ll need to refer to it later, for example at an employment tribunal.

There is a [free Acas helpline](https://www.gov.uk/pay-and-work-rights) where more qualified people can give you legal advice on your rights and responsibilities in this regard. But UK employment law is still fairly protective of workers rights, so I'd be astonished if a company could legally make it impossible for you to resign.

Comment: Thanks . If I send an email to the general HR contact and cc by boss and performance managers, is that sufficient for my resignation and notice period to take effect from when the email was received in their  inbox? They may argue I did not follow the policy of using the 'portal '

Comment: As Philip Kendall said, if you send a letter to the registered company address (best by registered mail), then they have legally received it, and can claim all they want, it's not going to help them. If they don't bother picking up that mail and reading it, you still have legally giving notice. Every UK company is legally required to read any mail going to their registered address, and if they don't, they are responsible for any damages caused.